# How to print http request with all the params?

Tags: java

This is a portion of code(somebody else wrote) that I am trying to understand. I want to print the request sent, but couldn't figure out a way to print url with all the params here.

```
//Obtain Response object returned by POST call to API with parameters passed in as HashMap
    public static Response getPOSTResponse(String query, String endpoint, HashMap<String, String> params) {
        //Initialize variables - for url and for data to be sent in POST request (need new hashmap for data due to type)
        String base_url = getUrl(endpoint);
        StringBuffer url = new StringBuffer();
        HashMap<String, List<Integer>> postData = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();

        url.append(base_url + "?");
        params.forEach((k, v) -> {
            String key = k;
            String value = (params.get(k));
            if (key.contains("list")) {
                postData.put(key, Collections.singletonList(Integer.parseInt(value)));
            } else { //should handle case for any [other] POST urls using parameters
                url.append(key);
                url.append("=");
                url.append(value);
                url.append("&");
            }
        });

        final RequestSpecification sender = given().headers("Content-Type", ContentType.JSON,
                                                            "Accept", ContentType.JSON);
                                                    
        return sender.when().body(postData).post(url.toString()).then().contentType(ContentType.JSON).extract().response();       

    }
```

Comment: Something like `System.out.prinln(url)` or `logger.debug(url)`?

Comment: I think you only need to print url variable after the forEach loop